# How can I setup Apache on Linux to stream WMV-HD to Xbox 360?

Tags: linux, streaming

What I am looking for is a free and open source solution. If the distro I use matters, it is Open SUSE. VLC supports only WMV1&2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up DLNA.  I don't know what packages on OpenSUSE would provide it, but it's your best bet.  Under Ubuntu, DLNA is provided by the package Rygel (although there is a plug in for Rhythmbox called Coherence).

Comment: I agree. There's a few DNLA/Xbox360 apps. I've used some (though not on Unix) and I'm yet to find one where HD streams really look HD.

Essentially when you get this hooked up it will show up as a video source in your library that you can connect to.

Comment: One DLNA alternative is PS3 media server http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/ (It says PS#, but it works with Xbox)